# How to generate 1Hz to 40Hz Waveform by ATMEGA32U4 (Arduino Board)

Tags: arduino, atmega, atmel

I am using ATMEGA32U4 (Arduino board ). I am facing problem with TIMER. I want to generate 1 Hz to 40 Hz signal in two pins and change PWM signal with certain period of time.

Example:

```
TIME | PIN9 Freq. | PIN9 PWM | PIN10 Freq. | PIN10 PWM | Alternate Mode  
T0   |    2Hz     |      50% |         2Hz |       50% | 0   
T1   |    3Hz     |      50% |        15Hz |       20% | 0  
T2   |   30Hz     |      40% |         2Hz |       50% | 0  
T3   |    2Hz     |      50% |         2Hz |       50% | 1
```

Alternate Mode activate gives 180 degree phase shift b/w PIN9 and PIN10.

Comment: Did you check the datasheet chapter on the use of timers? If so, could you link to it and you should probably be able to make the question more specific.

Comment: PWM @ 40hz is ridiculously slow for an AVR, so it should be straight forward to write a corresponding timer ISR.

Comment: If you set your timer interrupt to be triggered @ 150hz you can just count the ticks and toggle the outputs at the appropriate counts.

Comment: Oops. I guess that should have been 300Hz (least common multiple of all frequencies).

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick sketch:

```
#define F_TIMER_TICK 300 // in Hz

#define PHASE_NORMAL 0
#define PHASE_INVERSE 1

typedef struct pwmDef {
    uint8_t ticksOnPerCylce;
    uint8_t ticksPerCycle;
    uint8_t phase;
} pwmDef_t;

typedef struct doublePwmDef {
    pwmDef_t pin9;
    pwmDef_t pin10;
} doublePwmDef_t;

const doublePwmDef_t T0 = {
    { 
        (uint8_t) (F_TIMER_TICK / (2 / 0.5)),
        (uint8_t) ( F_TIMER_TICK / 2 ),
        PHASE_NORMAL
    },
    {
        (uint8_t) ( F_TIMER_TICK / (2 / 0.5) ),
        (uint8_t) ( F_TIMER_TICK / 2 ), 
        PHASE_NORMAL
    }
};

const doublePwmDef_t T1 = {
    { 
        (uint8_t) ( F_TIMER_TICK / (3 / 0.5) ),
        (uint8_t) ( F_TIMER_TICK / 3 ),
        PHASE_NORMAL
    },
    {
        (uint8_t) ( F_TIMER_TICK / (15 / 0.2) ),
        (uint8_t) ( F_TIMER_TICK / 15 ),
        PHASE_NORMAL
    }
};

const doublePwmDef_t T2 = {
...
};

const doublePwmDef_t T3 = {
    { 
        (uint8_t) (F_TIMER_TICK / (2 / 0.5)),
        (uint8_t) ( F_TIMER_TICK / 2 ),
        PHASE_NORMAL
    },
    {
        (uint8_t) ( F_TIMER_TICK / (2 / 0.5) ),
        (uint8_t) ( F_TIMER_TICK / 2 ), 
        PHASE_INVERSE
    }
};

// etc.

const doublePwmDef_t[] PWM_DEFS = {
    T0,
    T1,
    T2,
    T3
}

// etc.


volatile uint8_t mode;
volatile uint8_t tickCount9;
volatile uint8_t tickCount10;

ISR(TIMER0_COMPA_vect) {

    OCR0A += <trigger again in 1/300s>;

    const doublePwmDef_t currentPwmDef = PWM_DEFS[ mode ];

    if ( tickCount9 >= currentPwmDef.pin9.ticksPerCycle ) {
        tickCount9 = 0;
    }

    if (tickCount9 < currentPwmDef.pin9.ticksOnPerCylce) {
        if ( currentPwmDef.pin9.phase == PHASE_NORMAL ) {
            // Turn pin 9 ON
        } else {
            // Turn pin 9 OFF
        }
    } else {
        if ( currentPwmDef.pin9.phase == PHASE_NORMAL ) {
            // Turn pin 9 OFF
        } else {
            // Turn pin 9 ON
        }
    }

    tickCount9++;

    // Repeat the above for pin 10...

}

void switchMode( uint8_t newMode ) {
    cli();
    mode = newMode;
    tickCount9 = 0;
    tickCount10 = 0;
    sei();
}
```

If you use the right IO pins (e.g. OC1A and OC1B), you might be able to leverage hardware PWM, which I have not considered here; you could avoid writing an ISR at all in that case.

Comment: i am not able to configured  timer register getting error while runing code.